# My computer will connect to wireless networks for awhile and then stop

Tags: wireless, networking

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 on an HP laptop. The issue is that I will connect to wireless networks great for a few days. Then the computer will stop connecting almost as if it has forgotten how. I can still connect to the internet via a wired connection however that is inconvenient. I downloaded an earlier version of Ubuntu then this happened. Then, I reloaded that version and several others and all run into the same issue. Any advice on what I could do? I know my hardware is working properly, but maybe my router isn't talking well with my laptop. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its most likely your wireless card having power management issues try this.

This will keep power management enabled, but it will limit your wifi speed and range to 802.11g speeds.

1.Run the following commands

```
sudo rmmod iwlwifi

sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

2.Make sure that wireless connectivity is restored. To make this change permanent, use the following command:

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

3.Reboot to see changes.